# tabix.TabixError: query failed

Tags: python

I've been using pytabix to read through .gz files.
I'm not sure what's wrong with my code because it worked previously:

```
import tabix

tb = tabix.open('qcat.gz') 
coor = "chr10:6000-30000"
record = tb.querys(coor)                                                   
for res in record:        
    print res
```

I keep getting this error:

```
tabix.TabixError: query failed
```

It doesn't seem like an .tbi index file is being made.

Answer (score 1):

You ll have to run the prerequisites of tabix(bgzip, index) before the query actually.They are not included in the tb.query.

if your file is already zipped ,you should then do :

```
zippedf ='qcat.gz'
def tabix_index(zippedf)
    from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
    import shlex
    p = Popen(['tabix','-f', zippedf], stdout= PIPE)
    # or : cmd = "tabix -f " + zippedf
    # p = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE) 
    #(shlex splits the cmd in spaces)
    p.wait()
```

In case you have a non-zipped file you can run the 3 subprocesses in a row to do sorting ,bgzip and index :

```
out_sorted = 'myfile.sorted'
out_zipped= out_sorted + ".gz"

with open(out_zipped,'w') as sort_zip_out :
     cmd="sort -V  -k1,1   myfile"
     p1 = Popen( shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE )
     p2 = Popen(['bgzip','-c','-f'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout= sort_zip_out)
     p1.stdout.close()  #finish first subprocess before starting second
     p1.wait()  #wait for results to be written

#when these two subprocesses are finished, 
tabix_index(out_zipped)
```